# UITextField Should accept numbers only in iphone

Tags: iphone

UITextField have to accept the numbers only by using UITableView.

Answer (score 4):

You have to perform two steps:

1. Provide keyboard type as `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`, as mentioned by others.
2. In

   ```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
   ```

   method check that entered string in numeric or not.You can use following method to check numeric value:

   ```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
   {
       if([self isNumeric:string])
           return TRUE;
       else
           return FALSE;
   }

   -(BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString*)inputString
   {
       NSCharacterSet *cs=[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
       NSString *filtered;
       filtered = [[inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
       return [inputString isEqualToString:filtered];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In your xib file select the textFiled and in the property list there is a field Keyboard select Number Pad

Comment: This is not enough. A user can still paste any text into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have textFiled available while coding, set keyboardType property of UITextField.

```
 textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Or you can set the same with in xib file.

Comment: This is not enough. A user can still paste any text into the text field.